# Reference to type 'AuthenticationTicket' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 application, right now I am having some issues with migrating the code that I have from Core 1x. Here we have a small piece of code. I am having this errors, can anybody tell me if anything changed in this matter please?
PS: All four errors are the same:

> Reference to type 'AuthenticationTicket' claims it is defined in
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication', but it could not be found.

```
[errors in the code][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJNXy.png)

```
 private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request, ApplicationUser user, AuthenticationProperties properties = null)
    {
        // Create a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the claims that
        // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
        var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

        // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        ticket.SetResources(request.GetResources());**// ERROR IN THIS LINE**

        //if (!request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        //{
        // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
        // Note: the offline_access scope must be granted
        // to allow OpenIddict to return a refresh token.
        ticket.SetScopes(new[] **// ERROR IN THIS LINE**
        {
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
            }.Intersect(request.GetScopes())); **// ERROR IN THIS LINE**
        //}
}
```

UPDATE:
[Nuget references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch4lJ.png)

Comment: I think my answer is incorrect. What seems to have happened is the `SetResources` and `SetScopes` methods have been removed from `AuthenticationTicket` in Asp.Net Core 2. I'm trying to find where they are now, or the new method for it.

Comment: That will be awesome, thanks in advanced!

Comment: It seems the whole idea has changed, I can't find any reference to this methods on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Security). I guess if you want to set claims on the ticket you set them against the principal before you create the ticket. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/) for it is not bad and might have something.

Comment: that's something to work with, again, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your references list indicates that you're mixing packages designed for ASP.NET Core 1.x and packages that require 2.x. Since massive changes have been introduced between the 2 ASP.NET Core packages, authentication-related packages built for 1.x won't likely work with 2.0.

Try to update your packages to use ASP.NET Core 2.0-compatible versions. `AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation`, `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives`, `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` have all been updated to support the new authentication APIs (note: you don't need to reference the last 2 packages as they are indirectly referenced by OpenIddict).

Comment: Can you please tell me wich packages are for asp.net core 1x so I can remove them, I am quite new in asp.net core and it is really complicated. btw, thanks for the answer

Comment: @dayanrr91 you can start with the 3 packages I mentioned. To know if other packages are made for 1.x or 2.x you can type their name on https://www.nuget.org/ and see if they reference 1.x or 2.x ASP.NET Core packages.

Comment: E.g https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/2.0.0-rc1-final

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I didn´t notice that I was pointing at packages from Core 1x. I just upgraded them and the error got away.